# Count or list active client connections to mosquitto server

Tags: mosquitto

I just want to know how many clients are actively connected to my mosquitto server. Or even better, get a list of client ids connected to my mosquitto server.  I read some documentation suggesting the topic `$SYS/broker/clients/connected` will give this information.  But this command yielded no response and no results:

```bash
mosquitto_sub -h myserver.myserver.myserver -p 9500 -t $SYS/broker/clients/connected -u "my-user" -P "my-password" --capath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

(I replaced `myserver.myserver.myserver` and `my-user` and `my-password` with actual values.)  I verified the connection is working because if I publish a message to the same topic, the message appears.

How can I get a list of clients with active connection to my mosquitto server?  Or at least a numeric count of active connections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bah I figured it out. I need to put single quotes around the topic so that `$SYS` isn't interpreted as a variable. So like this:

```bash
mosquitto_sub -h myserver.myserver.myserver -p 9500 -t '$SYS/broker/clients/connected' -u "my-user" -P "my-password" --capath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
netstat -ntp | grep ESTABLISHED.*mosquitto
```

Which in my case outputs:

```
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.2:1883          10.42.0.18:56553        ESTABLISHED 448/mosquitto       
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.2:1883          10.42.0.19:54037        ESTABLISHED 448/mosquitto       
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.2:1883          10.42.0.11:49321        ESTABLISHED 448/mosquitto       
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.2:1883          10.42.0.15:48685        ESTABLISHED 448/mosquitto       
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.2:1883          10.42.0.12:57691        ESTABLISHED 448/mosquitto       
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.2:1883          10.42.0.13:56037        ESTABLISHED 448/mosquitto       
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.2:1883          10.42.0.17:40679        ESTABLISHED 448/mosquitto       
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.2:1883          10.42.0.16:39627        ESTABLISHED 448/mosquitto       
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.2:1883          10.42.0.14:33079        ESTABLISHED 448/mosquitto
```

If one only cares about the total count:

```
netstat -natp | grep ESTABLISHED.*mosquitto | wc -l
```

prints

```
9
```

`netstat` arguments: `-n` to avoid getting host names for ip addresses (faster), `-t` for TCP instead of UDP and `-p` to display program names so we can filter using grep.